# contador regresivo de tiempo entre 2 fechas php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tengo mi siguiente código .. me muestra lo que necesito, pero me gustaría ponerlo que avance.. o en este caso que vaya en cuenta regresiva... vi que lo hacen con js pero ni idea como hacerlo

```
<?php
$datetime1 = date_create('2009-10-11 19:10:15');
$datetime2 = date_create('2009-10-14 18:23:19');

if($datetime1 < $datetime2) {
     $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
     echo 'Faltan '.$interval->d." dias : ".$interval->h." horas : ".$interval->i." minutos : ".$interval->s." segundos ".' para el vencimiento.';
}
```

me muestra lo siguiente:

```
Faltan 2 dias : 23 horas : 13 minutos : 4 segundos  para el vencimiento.
```

Answer (score 1):

En efecto, lo que intentas lograr es mas fácil por medio de *JavaScript*. Usar *php* para una operación de este tipo, se me hace muy overkill. A menos que vayas a obtener la fecha de inicio del conteo de base de datos, aunque también podrías desde *Javascript* consultar un `WebAPI`. Pero en fin, lo que tu necesitas es lo siguiente:

```
<script>

var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2021 15:37:25").getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {


  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
```